# Как доступиться к callback клавиатуры?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграмм-бот. При создании клавиатуры
`kb_1 = keyboa_maker(items=answers, copy_text_to_callback=True)`
ответ пользователя сохраняется в какой то `callback`.
Мне далее нужно обратиться к ответу, и я не понимаю где он находиться

```
from keyboa import keyboa_maker
import telebot
import file_parser as parser
bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')

answers = ['Домашнюю', 'Сколько звезд на небе', 'Зачем носорогу рог']
kb_1 = keyboa_maker(items=answers, copy_text_to_callback=True)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Привет, это Бот-песочница Глеба, можешь по пользоваться, скоро будем тут тестировать технологии')
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=message.chat.id, reply_markup=kb_1,
        text="Что хотим узнать???")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if КАКАЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ == 'Домашнюю':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не скажу')
    elif КАКАЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ == 'Сколько звезд на небе':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Много')
    elif КАКАЯ_ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ == 'Зачем носорогу рог':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чтобы называться носорогом')
```

Comment: Приложите к своему вопросу полные логи с ошибкой, чтобы другим людям было проще понять вашу проблему.

Comment: @JoshJohnson ошибки нет, я просто выбираю что то из клавиатуры, а ответа нет, т.к. я не могу с помощью if проверить что ввел юзер, т.к. не знаю где лежит это значение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот код, который должен вам помочь с решением вашего вопроса:

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'Домашнюю':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Не скажу')
    elif call.data == 'Сколько звезд на небе':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Много')
    elif call.data == 'Зачем носорогу рог':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Чтобы называться носорогом')
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, в общем случае проблема решена, но message.chat.id не работает, message не определена, а если получать id статично, то все сообщения приходят последнему вошедшему пользователю

Comment: Забил вам сказать `call.message.chat.id` пишите так и заработает
Ещё раз простите за мою невнимательность

Comment: Да ничего страшного. Спасибо, все работает вроде. Но если вам не трудно, обьясните пожалуйста, что это значит: func=lambda call: True.

Comment: Поставь галочку если хочешь меня отблагодорить

Comment: Хорошо, ето базовая лямбда которая гласит всегда принимать ответи пользователей, ее можна менять и делать чтобы отвечал только каждому второму

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо еще раз

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы `inline`-клавиатура работала корректно  - требуется проверить какой из callback-ов поступил в обработчик.

Простой пример:

```
...
button = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
new = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Тест', callback_data='test')
button.add(new)
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Это пример строки', reply_markup=button)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call:True)
def send_text(call):
    if call.data == 'test':
        return bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Это тест кнопки')
```